# how to insert value in image datatype table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012-express

I am using Sql-Server 2012. In it  i made a column named Image with datatype image in Person table. Please explain that how can i add value in it? I mean should i have to define a path of any photo? or is there any other way to insert images in this column? Looking forward to your guidance

Person --Table name
person_name -- Column name with datatype nvarchar(50)
Image -- Column name with datatype image
Date -- Column name with datatype date

Or insertion is like: `

```
INSERT INTO Person  Values
( 'Person34', '  
SELECT  *  
       FROM OPENROWSET  
      ( BULK 'C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Lighthouse.jpg',SINGLE_CLOB)' , '2013-09-08');
```

`
**Thank You.**

Answer (score 1):

this is how I do it to save the image inside the BLOB/Image DB field.

```
/// <summary>
/// Saves the file into a BLOB/Image field in the DB
/// This uses an UPDATE command, therefore the record must alreay exist in the DB
/// </summary>
/// <param name="aTableName"></param>
/// <param name="aFieldName"></param>
/// <param name="aWhereClause"></param>
/// <param name="aFileName"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public bool SaveToBLOB(string aTableName, string aFieldName, string aWhereClause, string aFileName)
{
  string sSQL = string.Format("UPDATE {0} SET {1}=@{1} WHERE {2}", aTableName, aFieldName, aWhereClause);
  using (SqlCommand oComm = new SqlCommand(sSQL, m_Conn))
  {
    byte[] wFileAsByteArr = CDBConn.GetFileAsByteArray(aFileName);

    oComm.Parameters.Add("@" + aFieldName, SqlDbType.Image, wFileAsByteArr.Length).Value = wFileAsByteArr;
    return oComm.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0;
  }
}
```

And this  is how I retrieve it:
    /// 
    /// extract the first field (BLOB) of the specified SQL Command and save it as a file
    /// 
    /// 
    /// 
    /// true if the file was created and false otherwise
    public bool ExtractBLOB(string aSQLCommand, string aFileName)
    {
        using (SqlCommand oComm = CreateCommand())
        {
            oComm.CommandText = aSQLCommand;
            oComm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

```
        // Create a file to hold the output.
        using (System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(aFileName, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
        {
            using (System.IO.BinaryWriter bw = new System.IO.BinaryWriter(fs))
            {
                byte[] b = (byte[])oComm.ExecuteScalar();
                if (b != null)
                {
                    bw.Write(b);
                    bw.Flush();
                    return true;
                }
                else
                    return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where the aSQLCommand will be: SELECT MyImageField FROM TableABC WHERE ...

Comment: Thank you for sharing but i want to execute query in sql-server 20102.